# How to detect esc key press while showing jquery notification

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect the key event of escape while displaying the jquery notification. But as this is blocking the input I'm unable to detecting key board event while noty is showing.

Comment: I also looking for this solution.

Comment: See here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Please always searching in existing answers first.There are a lot of answers available of stack overflow regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
     //your codes 
  }   

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code It Works Everywhere:

```
// define a handler
function doc_keyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {//27 is Esc KeyCode
    alert('Escape Key Has Been Pressed!');
    }
}
// register the handler 
document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onkeyup to pass event handler like-

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="YourKeyupHandler(event)">
```

Now you can implement function like-

```
function YourKeyupHandler(event) {
    event = event || window.event || event.srcElement;
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        //here you can do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: event = event || window.event || event.srcElement; is an important line that will populate event in most of browsers